# "Fixed bad collision on certain clutter objects" v1.9 patch bug fix - What exactly does it fix?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The [v1.9 patch has this as one of its fixes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Beta_1.9.26.0.8):

> Fixed bad collision on certain clutter objects

I was wondering if this is related to this physics "objects flying all over the place" bug: [Skyrim "Flying" Objects](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64087/4797). If yes, does this mean that I can now disable v-sync or stop limiting my framerate? (The answers in that question recommend disabling vsync or using a framerate limiter to fix that bug.)

Or does it fix another bug or other bugs too? What exactly does it fix? (The bug fix description is not specific.)

I am playing on the PC.

Comment: You cannot disable VSync yet. First of all, why would you? Having more fps than your monitor can handle leads to tearing which you don't want. Second, this is adresses issues with stuff on the ground and getting stuck on it while walking. Also, the vsync issue is related to timings and physics and if you disable it, the day schedule of your npc's gets messed up. Totally different problem.

Comment: @user28015 That is what I am asking. If you're sure about that, could you put it as an answer? As to why I would want to disable Vsync, "*\[Enabling vsync\] can lead to a significant reduction in video performance in certain situations. These situations arise when framerate drops below refresh rate. In these situations your performance can drop by up to 50% in the worst case.*" - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/23251/4797 - I'd prefer to see some tearing for a significant increase in framerate. Not all of us have a high-end gaming PC.

Comment: @user28015 "*Also, the vsync issue is related to timings and physics... Totally different problem.*" Actually the "physics problem" can be fixed by enabling Vsync. See https://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1280991-do-not-disable-vsync/ & http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103571/4797. And that is what I was asking: *if* this bug fix by the v1.9 patch *is* related to that "physics - objects flying all over the place" bug. If not, what exactly does it fix?

Comment: Galactic, could you add the pc tag to your question? You do have it in your question, but its at the end and perhaps people should see it in the tags. Just that small edit would be **perfecto!**

Comment: @MissSkyrim I didn't add [pc] as the question is not entirely PC specific. See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless for more info.

Comment: @MissSkyrim The use of platform tags is only kinda accepted and still somewhat disputed, so they're not rigidly enforced. If the tag isn't used, mentioning the platform in the question body is usually acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular fix is just a minor patch to some hit-boxes and not a change for the physics engine which would be required to ultimately solve the flying item bugs that appear when VSync has been disabled.

Clutter objects are objects that are placed in the game world without having any particular function other than to provide atmosphere. Examples of clutter objects are brooms, unreadable books, kitchenware etc. There is a list of them over at [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Miscellaneous_Items#Clutter). This fix just corrects the hit-boxes on some of these clutters objects that have been incorrect. Notice in the Flying Objects questions that essentially all items are sent flying out of control while this fix only corrects a small number of objects with no function.